# How to invoke with reflection a method that accepts a Func<> parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, methods, reflection

When I try to add the `Func<>` parameter in the array of `MethodInfo.Invoke`, it's giving me the error that it can't convert a method group to an object.

How do I deal with this?

The method's signature:

`static bool Something(Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression> body)`

What I'm passing:

`MethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { Expression.Subtract }); // compilation error`

> CS0428 Cannot convert method group 'Subtract' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: I've added proper error message and more research. Should be good... or strange... not sure. Feel free to revert. But explain what is unclear about the error message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed no conversion from method groups to `object`, but there *are*  conversions from method groups to compatible delegate types ([method group conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#method-group-conversions)), and there are also conversions from delegate types to `object`. So you can first convert the method group to `Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression>` with a cast, then it can be implicitly converted to `object`:

```
someMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { (Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression>)Expression.Subtract });
```

Comment: @SpiritBob Or in other words, C# has no idea what delegate type you want to create, normally it would infer this.